# A dual norm problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\|.\|$ denote any norm on $C^m$. The corresponding dual norm $\|.\|'$ is defined by the formula  $\|x\|' = sup_{\|y\|=1}|y^*x|$.

Let $x, y \in C^m $ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ be given. Show that there exists a rank-one matrix $B=yz^*$ such that $Bx=y$ and $\|B\| =1$, where $\|B\|$ is the matrix norm of B induced by the vector norm   $\|.\| $. You may use the following lemma, without proof: given  $x\in C^m $ there exists a nonzero $z \in C^{m}$ such that $|z^*x|= \|z\|^{'}\|x\|$.

My method: $Bx=y \Longrightarrow yz^*x=y\Longrightarrow \lVert z \rVert^{'}=1, $ But what is the next step?

Comment: You need $z^{\ast} x = 1$. Can you get that from the lemma?

Comment: @DanielFischer No so I'm confused

Comment: Since you have $\lVert x\rVert = 1$, the lemma gives you a nonzero $z_0$ with $\lvert z_0^{\ast} x\rvert = \lVert z_0\rVert'$. With $z_1 = \frac{1}{\lVert z_0\rVert'}\cdot z_0$, you have $\lvert z_1^{\ast} x\rvert = \lVert z_1\rVert' = 1$. Can you find a $z_2 = c\cdot z_1$ such that $z_2^{\ast} x = \lvert z_1^{\ast} x\rvert$?

Comment: @Why do you want to find a such $z_2$. And I think the next step may be to find a a $B=yz^*$ such that $\|B\|=1$

Comment: $y$ is fixed. Given any $z$, what is $\lVert yz^{\ast}\rVert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know how to compute this guy..

Comment: Start with the definition of $\lVert B\rVert$. Do you know what "matrix norm induced by the vector norm" means?

Comment: OK I got it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Now I have another confuse. By definition we have $\|B\|=\sup\limits_{\|q\|=1}\|Bq\|$ which means $1=\|y\|=\|Bq\|\leq\|B\|\|q\|\Longrightarrow\|B\|\geq1$ But how to prove that $|B\|\leq1$ so we can get $\|B\|=1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Please tell me how to tackle this. Thanks